# URL Amigável com parâmetro variavel

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte expressão regular para URL Amigavel:

```
RewriteRule ^categoria/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ categoria.php?idc=$1&nome=$2&pg=$3 [NC]
```

gostaria de deixar o 3 parâmetro, o pg, opcional, ter ou não ter. Da forma que estou utilizando é obrigatório fornecer o 3 parâmetro.

Comment: Tem vários exemplos no site, e tem mais de um com parâmetros opcionais, veja qual serve melhor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+amigavel

Answer (score 2):

Tentou isso?

```
RewriteRule ^categoria\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/([a-z0-9-]+)(\/([a-z0-9-]+))?\/?$ categoria.php?idc=$1&nome=$2&pg=$4 [NC]
```

Assim você coloca um grupo dentro do outro e faz o parâmetro pai ser opcional englobando a barra. Na variável de resposta é só pular o parâmetro pai ($3) até encontrar o parâmetro filho ($4).