# URL Amigável: Como inserir valor de uma variável em php dentro de uma URL

Tags: php, htaccess

Estou trabalhando em um sistema PHP de anúncios para profissionais autônomos onde estou tendo dificuldades de incluir o título desse anúncio dentro da URL da página tornando-a uma URL amigável. Encontrei algumas questões similares, mas infelizmente não consegui resolver a questão:

1. [Passando variáveis pela URL utilizando URL amigáveis via GET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27534/passando-vari%C3%A1veis-pela-url-utilizando-url-amig%C3%A1veis-via-get)
2. [URL amigável automática em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142130/url-amig%c3%a1vel-autom%c3%a1tica-em-php)
3. [URL Amigável com parâmetro variavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128546/url-amig%c3%a1vel-com-par%c3%a2metro-variavel)

No caso, atualmente a URL da página do anúncio esta assim:

**URL atual:**

```
https://meusite.com.br/anuncio?id=10
```

E gostaria que a URL ficasse da seguinte forma abaixo onde após a / fosse inserida o valor de uma variável em php:

**URL desejada:**

```
https://meusite.com.br/anuncio/titulo-do-anuncio-aqui
```

Para criar um link para redirecionar o usuário para a página do anúncio, inseri uma variável chamada **$row['id']** dentro de uma href conforme abaixo:

```
<a href="anuncio?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['tituloAnuncio'].'</a>
```

Conforme a tag  link acima, a variável $row provem de um while relacionado uma query select que é executada corretamente dentro da página.

Por fim, tentei configurar o Htaccess da seguinte forma abaixo, porém por eu ser iniciante nessa área, não consegui configurar corretamente bem como encontrar uma maneira correta para configurar a URL desejada:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^anuncio\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ anuncio.php?id=$1
```

No caso como faço para utilizar o valor da variável $row['tituloAnuncio'] dentro da URL da página do anúncio conforme abaixo?

```
https://meusite.com.br/anuncio/professor-particular-ou-online
```

Comment: Não entendi bem... Seu link usa `$row['id']` que suponho ser numérico e quer que a URL seja usando `$row['tituloAnuncio']`? Se alguem acessar `https://meusite.com.br/anuncio?id=10` você quer que seja feito um redirecionamento ou quer que a URL aponte direto pro título?

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback @PapaCharlie. A ideia seria essa mesmo, se possível. No caso atualmente a página é acessada por esse formato de url ```https://meusite.com.br/anuncio?id=10``` onde o id é identificado como ```$row[id]```, porém a ideia seria que a url fosse assim ```https://meusite.com.br/anuncio/titulo-do-anuncio-aqui```, porém não sei como fazer essa configuração tanto quanto no htaccess quanto no php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte: a url que o apache recebeu não é compatível com a expressão regular da regra que você passou.
Isso por que ela está esperando um texto que contenha: 1) o site; 2) o diretorio 'anuncio'; **3) um número;** e 4) um texto.

Você está passando: 1) o site; 2) o diretório 'anuncio'; e 3) um texto

Dito isto, sugiro duas soluções para seu problema:

A primeira e mais simples seria passar o ID juntamente com o titulo na URL, por exemplo:

`https://meusite.com.br/anuncio/10/professor-particular-ou-online`

Isso já funciona com sua regra de reescrita (abaixo), mas você não está passando o ID. Você pode testar [aqui](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=a76d57d9-d0bf-4182-a2bf-12600d88a448)

```
RewriteRule ^anuncio\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ anuncio.php?id=$1
```

A outra alternativa, ***que se adequa a URL sugerida***,  seria você mapear para o script PHP decidir como um título se relaciona com um id.

Para isso, você precisaria modificar a regra de reescrita (deixando do jeito que você sugeriu) e pode testar [aqui](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c9c08f00-6167-483a-b4e0-98008ee05ca5):

```
RewriteRule ^anuncio\/?(.+)\/?$ anuncio.php?titulo=$1
```

Isso iria funcionar, mas você não teria o ID ao chegar na página **anuncio.php** e sim o título, portanto precisará criar uma estratégia para buscar pelo título e não pelo ID. Neste caso, você precisa garantir que não haverão títulos duplicados ou vazios, do contrário seu script não irá funcionar adequadamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcos. Segui a sua orientação e consegui adaptar a minha aplicação. Valeu!